# Android, how to update UI while sending Data over bluetooth

Tags: java, android

I have a button on my app that when I click (takes me to the picture gallery with an intent for result). When I select the picture, I get the result back fine, and then start transfering the image using a stand alone method.

The problem is that the UI gets stuck at the gallery screen and then the screen goes dark, until the transfer is complete... I try to update the UI using run on ui, but it doesn't work...

```
while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1)
        {
            BT_data_out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            if(fill++ > 2) {BT_data_out.flush(); fill = 0;};
            prgrss += bytesRead;
            final String done = Integer.toString(prgrss);
            final String total = Integer.toString(fileL);

            if(update_rate > (50000/bufSize) ) {
                update_rate = 0;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        mTextMISC.setText(done+"/"+total+" B");
                    }
                });

            }
            update_rate++;
        }
```

Once the transfer is complete I can see the final effect of the UI thread, but all the intermediatary updates are never seen.

Comment: You'd better create a new thread to transfer data;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot natively make updates to the main UI thread from a secondary thread. In order to do this you have to attach a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to the main UI thread and post messages to it from the secondary. Alternatively you can use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which is Androids implementation and makes using threads and handlers that much easier.